# Bootstrap modal width

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a modal popup change it's width so that it matches col-lg-8, col-xs-10

But I just found that modal is fixed width.

So, then I found a css styling that can change the width:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mdlBudgets" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content modal-graph col-lg-8 col-xs-10  well well-sm">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left debit_colour"></span> <strong>Budgets</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            @if (Model.BarDescriptions.Length == 0)
            {
                <small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign debit_colour"></span> You have no Budgets setup yet.</small>
            }
            else
            {
                <div id="budgets"></div>
            }

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-right"><a href="@Url.Action("Budgets", "Budget")" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> View Budgets</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body .modal-graph {
    /* new custom width */
    width: 700px;
    /* must be half of the width, minus scrollbar on the left (30px) */
    margin-left: 350px;
}
```

However, firstly, it's off centre, but my biggest issue is - it's a fixed size. Is there a way to make my modal-graph act like  col-lg-8, col-xs-10 ?

Comment: Does the native classes aren't usefull in your case ? http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-sizes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said `.modal-dialog` has fixed width so you have to overwrite it. Then to use `col-xx-xx class`, you have to center them. Something like:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="mdlBudgets" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog as-container">
        <div class="modal-content modal-graph col-lg-8 col-xs-10  well well-sm">

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-left debit_colour"></span> <strong>Budgets</strong>
                </div>
            </div>
            @if (Model.BarDescriptions.Length == 0)
            {
                <small><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign debit_colour"></span> You have no Budgets setup yet.</small>
            }
            else
            {
                <div id="budgets"></div>
            }

            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 text-right"><a href="@Url.Action("Budgets", "Budget")" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> View Budgets</a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and css:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .modal-dialog.as-container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .modal-dialog.as-container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .modal-dialog.as-container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}

.modal-dialog.as-container .modal-content {
    float: none;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: If I want my default modals to use the normal sizing, and have special modals for graphs, can I just rename the class to something like "modal-graph.as-container"?

Comment: "as-container" is a class that I added. probably bad name - just meant to take same width as a "container". For your default modals DO NOT add this class and they will work normally.

Comment: Ah, thanks for that! Perfect. I am just battling with some small things. I'll mark answer very soon.Good work!